# How to temporarily block selectable elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a popup menu on my webpage. The menu contains various selectable items, and I would like to only allow selection of certain items after a top-selection has been made. Now I could hide all items lower-down, but that would make the popup look weird. I'd rather show them, but dimmed. My idea was to enclose the follow-up selections in a div, and have that div act as a blocker. Now the question is how to do it - I tried setting the z-index of the selBlocker div higher than the rest, also to give it absolute positioning, but didn't get anywhere yet. I am using a javascript library to handle the selections in general.

```
<div id="SelPopup" >
    <div id="topSelect"></div>

    <div id="selBlocker">
         <div id="selectable2"></div>
         <div id="selectable3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you set up a first example as a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions, I actually found what I was looking for:

```
$("#selBlocker").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

This will nicely disable all interaction, and with

```
$("#selBlocker").css("pointer-events", "all");
```

I can restore it. Can add the change in opacity easily alongside it.

Answer (score 0):

I would append a class to the items you dont want to select, and add the not() selector to your jQuery.

For example:

```
$("div:not('.selected').....
```

Instead of

```
$("div").....
```

Ofcourse you can add an opacity to the class .selected, to make it a little bit less visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

Instead of using `id` for selection blocked element use `class="selectBlocked"` and for menu div use `class="selectMenu"`

```
<div id="SelPopup" >
    <div id="topSelect" class="selectMenu"></div>

    <div id="selBlocker1" class="selectMenu selectBlocked">
         <div id="selectable2"></div>
         <div id="selectable3"></div>
    </div>
   <div id="selBlocker4" class="selectMenu selectBlocked">
         <div id="selectable5"></div>
         <div id="selectable6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now right jQuery for handling selection of menu and do nothing if selected menu is with class="selectBlocked"

```
$('.selectMenu').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass("selectBlocked"))
        return false;

    // do your stuff if above condition fails
});
```